# Setting a dynamic range to Fill Down

Tags: excel, dynamic, vba

I'm very new to using VBA with my excel workbooks.

I came across the following piece of code that @Manhattan provided as an answer to another question.  It suits the needs of my workbook perfectly, but I need help with setting up a dynamic range.

What I am struggling to do now, is make the code only fill down enough rows to match up with the rows in column P (Which is the Row Labels column of the pivot table which the code below is pulling data from), except for the very last row (which is always "Grand Totals")?

```
Sub FillDown()

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        strFormulas(1) = "=SUM($Q3:$S3)"
        strFormulas(2) = "=iferror(index(q3:s3,match($AE$2,$Q$2:$S$2,0)),0)"
        strFormulas(3) = "=$AD3-$AE3"

        .Range("AD3:AF3").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("AD3:AF150").FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

TL;DR:  How can I make this code only fill down enough rows to match the last row -1 in column P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically find the last row of column P (LR):

```
Dim LR as Long
LR = .Cells( .Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
```

Then apply the last row minus 1 to your filldown:

```
.Range("AD3:AF" & LR-1).FillDown
```